# How to kill all background and spawned processes of a bash script in its pre-exit handler?

Tags: bash, signals, parallelism, job-control, wait

I'm using the `wait -n` technique to perform `max_jobs` parallel tasks:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cleanup() {
    echo "cleaning up..."
}

trap "cleanup" EXIT

do_task() {
    echo "doing task" "$1"  " ..."
    sleep 3s
}

main_task() {
    for ((j = 0; j < 10; j++)); do
        ((i++ < max_jobs)) || wait -n
        do_task "$j" &
    done
    wait
}

i=0
max_jobs=4

main_task
```

How can I kill all jobs and processes spawned by this script (in `cleanup` handler) if I hit `Ctrl+C` ?

I tried `kill 0` in `cleanup`, but it doesn't seem to kill the dangling `do_task` jobs.

Note that if I send `SIGTERM` (`Ctrl+C`) in first 3 seconds, it kills the script. But if I wait until 5s and then send `SIGTERM`, suddenly one dangling process consumes 100% of the CPU as if it is stuck in an infinite loop. I have to eyeball that process in `htop` and send `SIGKILL` to it manually.

Comment: I trust there is a reason why you do not use GNU Parallel (which does the above) which is not mentioned on https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ Can you elaborate why?

Comment: @OleTange well, at the end of the day, it's another dependency. But, I've just finished reading the "15 minutre" part of the tutorial pdf a couple of days ago. It's a handy tool, thanks for writing that! I figure, if I had to use it, I would use `sem` and `sem --wait` right?

Comment: @OleTange Also I think `gnu parallel` is more suitable for standalone programs not bash functions? Cause the bash function better not utilize any global variables so `export -f func` would be valid

Comment: `env_parallel` is made for accessing non-exported variables, arrays, functions, and aliases: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/env_parallel.html#bash GNU Parallel is designed to both support bash functions and stand-alone programs.

Comment: Typically you would not use `sem`: You can almost always rewrite the code to use `(env_)parallel` and have it look cleaner.

Comment: As for dependency: Are you aware of `parallel --embed`?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: Use GNU Parallel instead.

```
parallel --embed > myscript.sh
```

Append this to `myscript.sh`:

```
env_parallel --session
do_task() {
    echo "doing task" "$1"  " ..."
    sleep 3s
}
seq 40 | env_parallel -j4 do_task
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> will now kill all `do_task`s.